# Multiple simple_html_dom () object creation

Tags: php, html, dom, simple-html-dom

I am creating a web scraper using the php simple html dom library.
I am working on a web scraping project where on one php page i load an html page for scraping and inside that i call a function on another php page which also loads an html page or pages. The problem is that i am unable to load the second html page. Below are the functions that i use on both pages for loading an html page for scraping.
first page

```
include ('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = new simple_html_dom ();
$html->load_file ( $link );
```

first page

```
$html = new simple_html_dom ();
$html->load_file ( $link );
```

When the code calls the second php page, i get the following error

```
Undefined variable: html
```

Answer (score 1):

Well...I hope I understood your question...Let see if this answers your question.

Make sure you call this next line on every page...

```
include ('simple_html_dom.php');
```

Then I call

```
$html = new simple_html_dom ();
$html->load_file ( $link );
```

NOW if I need to call two different XML files well I will do it like this

```
$html = new simple_html_dom ();
$html->load_file ( $link );
$detail = new simple_html_dom ();
$detail->load_file ( $link2 );
```

You could actually load the same XML using this next method if you want...

```
$html = new simple_html_dom ();
$html->load_file ( $link );
$html2 = new simple_html_dom ();
$html2->load_file ( $link );
```